# Unable to find path to signing tool

Tags: c#

I am trying to release an application, but am failing because the program cannot find the path to the signing tool.  Any ideas?

> An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe was not found at path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\signtool.exe.

Comment: did you check https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2013/11/18/an-error-occurred-while-signing-signtool-exe-not-found/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please make sure that the file is available there. Signtool.exe is
>   part of the windows platform SDK. If the file is not present on the
>   system, please install/repair  windows platform SDK OR copy the file
>   from a working system.

For more, [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2013/11/18/an-error-occurred-while-signing-signtool-exe-not-found/).